# How do i add space between this php variables

Tags: php, html, attributes, whitespace

So this works great when posted to the db. `NameWeb Developer` but what i wanted is `Name Web Developer`. am concatenating the value veriable i don't if is posible. below is the code.

```
            $spName .= $row['firstname'];
            $spPro = $row['profession'];

            $options .= '<option value='. $spName . '' . $spPro .'>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . ' - ' . $row['profession'] . '</option>';
            // or i could also do it this way.                                                                                                              
            $options .= '<option value='. $row['firstname'] . '' . $row['profession'] .'>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . ' - ' . $row['profession'] . '</option>';
```

But still not adding space between them.

Comment: would be better to assign all those variables into a single variable to hold them. doing it like that is just messy and confusing.

Comment: please can contribute to the question instead of just down-voting.

Comment: Well, what is the HTML generated by this code?  Where do you want to put the space character?  What happens when you... type a space there?

Comment: I actually did not down-vote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generating invalid HTML.  This:

```
'<option value='. $spName . ' ' . $spPro .'>'
                             ^--- WITH the added space
```

Will produce something like this:

```
<option value=SomeName SomeProfession>
```

The browser has no way of knowing that these two values are part of the same attribute.  In short, you *forgot the quotes*.  You want to generate something like this:

```
<option value="SomeName SomeProfession">
```

So put the quotes in your code:

```
'<option value="'. $spName . ' ' . $spPro .'">'
```

In short, *always* look at the actual HTML that's in your web browser when debugging this.  Don't just look at what ends up in the database somewhere downstream in the system, but look at the actual steps which *lead* to that downstream result.  Invalid HTML is often fairly obvious to see when you look at the HTML itself.

Comment: absolutely. very well explain Dave. i tried it and it works just like i wanted and yet another learning curve. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put a space between `$spName` and `$spPro`.

```
$options .= '<option value='. $spName . ' ' . $spPro .'>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . ' - ' . $row['profession'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Actually have done it exactly like this before and does not work. but i will give another go.

Comment: @Abhijit.Parida have tried your suggestion but that only give me the name without the profession

Comment: @lekanoshodi: That would seem to suggest that you have an error somewhere else.  Because literally all this (correct) answer does is add a space character where you imply that you want a space character.  You use the spacebar to type this character where you want it in your code.  If there's some other problem then you'll need to specify that.  But at the moment all you're asking is how to type a space character.

Comment: @David... i guess you are right... as you can see in my original code i added space in the HTML code with the same syntax suggested, is just that it does not work inside the option value. But anyway thanks for all your helps tho.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question since you clearly show that you know how to add space between 2 variables

```
$var1 .' '.$var2;
```

it seems however with your code there is an error

$row['firstname'] . '' . $row['profession']

adds nothing between 2 variables cause I think you forgot the space: ' ' and used nothing: '' instead.

Answer (score -1):

`&nbsp;` is used for adding space in html and php

You can add `&nbsp;` html in between name and profession

Here is your fixed code

```
$spName .= $row['firstname'];
            $spPro = $row['profession'];

            $options .= '<option value='. $spName . '' . $spPro .'>' . $row['firstname'] . '&nbsp; ' . $row['lastname'] . ' - ' . $row['profession'] . '</option>';
            // or i could also do it this way.                                                                                                              
            $options .= '<option value='. $row['firstname'] . '&nbsp;' . $row['profession'] .'>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . ' - ' . $row['profession'] . '</option>';
```

Comment: Improve it to make it cleaner and not repetitive.

Comment: @JShabu... sorry mate i can't see the different in my code and yours, please you kindly highlight your fix.

Comment: Why does the *value* need an HTML non-breaking space?

Comment: @hungrykoala take your point mate and i will try and so that, whilst am doing that are you able to advise how to add space between the value `firstname and profession`?

Comment: @lekanoshodi &nbsp; is added for space in my code it is used for adding space.

Comment: remember guys i could use echo and break the line if wanted to print on the page directly. but i wanted to post inside database first so i need space between the values posted

Comment: @J.Shabu thanks but i need the space inside option value `value='. $spName . '' . $spPro .'>`